# Docker: Monitor logical units of linked containers

Tags: docker, monitor, docker-compose

I'm running several micro-services in docker containers. Each service consists of 2 or more containers that I start/stop using docker-compose.

As the number of containers grows I'd like to monitor them, but I haven't found a method or (self-hosted) tool to monitor linked containers as a logical unit (service) instead of every single container, yet.
Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be included in a project like [Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/), which [groups containers in a **pod**](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/pods.md#pods).

You can then run [**Heapster**](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/monitoring.md#overview), a cluster-wide aggregator of monitoring and event data. The Heapster pod discovers all nodes in the cluster and queries usage information from the nodes’ [Kubelets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/DESIGN.md#kubelet), the on-machine Kubernetes agent.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/docs/user-guide/monitoring-architecture.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ruxit](https://blog.ruxit.com/full-stack-docker-performance-monitoring-containers-and-applications/) that provides service-oriented monitoring for Docker containers. It automatically detects the services in the containers and show them as separate entities on the dashboard even if a service is provided by multiple containers across hosts.

[image: See how a single service is provided by multiple containers]